# difference between maximal element and greatest element

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I know that it's very elementary question but I still don't fully understand difference between maximal element and greatest element. If it's possible, please explain to me this difference with some examples etc.

I tried to explain this difference to myself using only definition, but maximal element and greatest element still seems almost the same for me.

Thank you.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/96018/1457

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You are *maximal* when there is nobody above you.

You are *greatest* when you are above everyone else.

Examples:

- If nobody has eaten you, it doesn't follow that you have eaten everyone else.
- If nobody is standing on your head, it doesn't follow that you are standing on everyone else's head.
- If you live on the top floor of your apartment building, it doesn't follow that you live above everyone else in the city.

So maximal elements need not be greatest.

(Incidentally, although a greatest element is always a unique maximal element, it is a fun exercise to come up with a partial order having a *unique* maximal element, which is not greatest.)

Comment: I gave an example in my answer for such partial order.

Comment: Ah, yes indeed you did.

Comment: Your apartment illustration is very nice!

Comment: The world needs more answers like this.

Comment: Just linked here from to my profile :) I think I will try to make a big list of good answers.

Comment: @goblin Wow! I am honored.

Comment: Is it possible to have a greatest element as well as another maximal element?

Comment: @ahorn No, because to be greatest, it must be above all other elements, and so those other elements cannot be maximal.

Comment: @JDH This is great. The first two lines made me laugh.

Comment: @JDH:I'm studying connectedness in topology.I wanted to prove that COMPONENTS are MAXIMAL CONNECTED subsets.What should I Show in order to prove this?

Comment: @JDH I think this is an example of a partial order with a unique maximal element which is not greatest: $\mathbb{N}$ with the usual order along with a new element $x$ that is incomparable to any natural number. $x$ is the only maximal element but it is not a maximum. Is there a finite, or more natural, example? What can be said about the class of partial orders that satisfy your criterion?

Comment: @user76284 Indeed, you've solved it. One thing that you can say about those orders is that they are all infinite.

Comment: Regarding the apartment example: the situation you described doesn't imply that you're a greatest element, does it? The fact that you live on the top floor of your apartment building only says that you're above (or on the same level as) everyone else but only in your building. Or am I missing something? If my argument is correct, then is this apartment example not an example of a greatest element that isn't maximal?

Comment: @user557 It's the other way around: the apartment example (and all the other examples) is an example of a maximal element which is not the greatest element.

Comment: But furthermore, greatest elements are always maximal, so there is no example the other way.

Answer (score 45):

The crucial issue is the difference between a partial order and a linear order.

A partial order is a set where *sometimes* you can say "this thing is bigger than that", but some things are just incomparable.  In a linear order, you can *always* say "this thing is bigger than that."

For example, if you're working with the natural numbers (except $0$), $\{1,2,3,...\}$, and you say "I'm going to declare that $n \leq m$ iff $n|m$.  Then, reflexivity is clear ($n|n$), antisymmetry is clear (if $n|m$ and $m|n$, then $n = m$.  And transitivity is also easy to check ($n|m$ and $m|p$ implies $n|p$).  So, this really is a partial order.

Now, in *this* notion of order, is $2\leq 3$?  No, since $2$ doesn't divide evenly into 3.  Well, is $3\leq 2$?  Again, no, since $3$ doesn't divide evenly into $2$.  The conclusion is that we simply have no way of comparing the sizes of $2$ and $3$ in this order.

Now, to answer your actual question, as Stefan has noted, in a linear order (where any two elements are comparable) the two notions coincide.

In a partial order, we can see the difference.  An element is *maximal* if it's bigger than everything it can be compared to, but we're not claiming it can be compared to everything.
An element is *greatest* if it's bigger than everything it can be compared to, and we can compare it with everything.

Comment: Good answer. Along with Stefan's, the only clear ones on the page, as I see it! Once one realises that the poset concept isn't nearly so intuitive as a totally-ordered set, one can separate these concepts much more readily.

Comment: Best answer Ive read on the concept, especially the last paragraph.

Comment: Compared to the answer by @JDH, I think your answer is better! (Maybe I like to accept mathematic concepts in its own language)

Comment: Such a nice explanation. Looking for things like this. Wish someday I will also be able to make others understand things like this.

Comment: A slight refinement: in general, directed sets (which might not be linearly ordered) have the property that the notion of maximal and maximum coincide. Indeed, if $a$ is maximal, for any other element $b$ in the set, by definition there exists an element $c$ such that $a \le c$ and $b \le c$, but $a$ is maximal, so $a = c$ and so $b \le a$.

Answer (score 27):

Suppose $\langle A,R\rangle$ is a partially ordered set (i.e. $A$ is non-empty, $R$ is a partial order relation on $A$).

An element $a\in A$ is called *maximal* if $\forall b\in A(aRb\rightarrow b=a)$. That is, there is no one "above" $a$ (except perhaps $a$ itself).

An element $a\in A$ is called *maximum* or *greatest* if $\forall b\in A(bRa\lor b=a)$, that $a$ stands "above" *everyone* in $A$ in the relation $R$.

Note that both these definitions hold whether or not you require $R$ to be reflexive.

From this follows that a greatest element is by definition maximal, but not vice versa.

Consider the following case $A=\{a,b\}$ and $R$ is defined to be the identity relation, then both $a$ and $b$ are maximal, but neither is the greatest.

Another strong example with a single maximal element, but no greatest element is this: consider the set $\{a\}\cup\mathbb Z$, and the relation $R$ defined to be $<$ for integers and $aRa$ otherwise (i.e. $a$ does not stand with the integers in this relation). In this case $a$ is trivially a maximal element, no one is "above" it, however there is no maximum element, since no one stands over *both* $a$ and *all* the integers.

Comment: if i understand correctly, your example concerns the following partial order $\{a\} \bigcup \mathbb{Z}, <$. I'm not sure how you defines the the relation $R$ but $<$ is not reflexive. Can you explain your example a bit more?

Answer (score 12):

Suppose you have a set of boxes. A box that does not fit into any other box is *maximal*. A box into which any other box fits is *greatest*.

Answer (score 7):

In a totally ordered set those concepts are the same. So we need to consider partially ordered sets that are not totally ordered in order to find an example. The most common sets of that kind are sets of sets ordered by inclusion. Consider the set $\{\{0\},\{1\}\}$. It contains two elements, none of which is a subset of the other. Both elements are maximal, but the set has no greatest element.

Comment: Maybe I would not take the degenerate case as an example :-)

Answer (score 6):

Take an ordered set $(P,\leq)$. An element $g\in P$ is called greatest if for *every* $p\in P$ we have $p\leq a$. An element $m\in P$ is called maximal if there exists no $q\in P$ such that $m<q$. If $P$ is totally ordered then the two notions coincide. But in partially ordered sets the two notions are different. Here's an example:

Take all humans that have ever lived on earth (including those still alive) and order them as following $A<B$ if $B$ is a descendant of $A$ (this in fact is an ordering). Observe now that every person $P$ that doesn't have children yet is a maximal element of the aforementioned order, since  there doesn't exist any human that is  descendant of $P$. On the other hand this order doesn't have a greatest element. Such a person would need to be a descendant of every human that has ever lived, which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set ${2,3,4,6}$ under divisibility.  This set has 2 maximal elements since $2|4$, $2|6$ and $3|6$ where we write $a|b$ to mean means $b$ is divisible by $a$. Since we do not have $3|4$ or $4|6$, both $4$ and $6$ act as Maximal elements, but it has no greatest element.