# Question in Proof That Every Well-Ordering is a Total-Ordering

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, well-orders

I am trying to make sense of the following:

Theorem: Let $R$ be a relation on a set $A$. 
If $R$ is a well-ordered relation on $A$, then $R$ is a total-order relation on $A$.

Proof: Suppose $x,y\in A.$ Let $R=\{x,y\}\not=\emptyset$. By assumption, $R$ has a least element. If it is $x$, then $x\leq y$. If it is $y$, then $y\leq x$.

$$\text{__________________________________}$$

For a relation to be total ordered, then it must be that for each $x,y\in A$, $xRy$ and $yRx$. In this case we are comparing $x , y$ where one or the other is a least element. What about if neither is a least element though? Do we then simply say that $x,y$ must relate because if we consider whatever is the least element, say $z$, then both $x,y$ can relate to $z$ and therefore must relate to each other?

Comment: One of them must be the least element of $\{x,y\}$ because there are no other elements in the set, and it has a least element.

Comment: Where does this proof come from? In the definitions as I've learned them, well-ordered relations are defined to be both well-founded and totally ordered, and well-founded relations need not be totally ordered. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116642/is-well-founded-the-same-as-well-ordered

Comment: The definition my book uses denotes well-ordered relation as a partially-ordered relation on $A$ such that each non-empty subset of $A$ has a least element with respect to $R$.

Comment: @J.G.: Well-founded relations have a minimal element in each non-empty set; well-orders have a minimum in each non-empty set.

Comment: @AsafKaragila In other words, the minimal element of the non-empty set is only required to be unique in the latter case? Fair enough.

Comment: I am still having trouble following how this suggests that each element in the set is comparable. For instance, can't there be a partial ordered set with a least element with elements that are not comparable? In my mind, I am thinking of a Hasse diagram with a least element at the bottom and branches up to the top that do not connect. I am not sure how I would describe this more mathematically to explain my confusion.

Comment: @J.G.: Unique minimal is not the same as minimum in the general case.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'll back up. For well-founded relations, a non-empty set $S$ owns some $m$ such that no $x\in S$ satisfies $x<m$; for well-ordered relations, the choice of such $m$ is unique for each $S$. Is that statement right?

Comment: @J.G.: Yes, but the proof goes through linearity first. So you should either be fully accurate and state that $m$ is ***minimum*** (not "a unique minimal" as you state it, because these two things are not generally equivalent), or go all in and say that the order is linear and every non-empty set admits a minimal (which in turn has to be a minimum). The reason I keep insisting is that, again, in general there are partial orders with a unique *minimal* element which is not a minimum.

Comment: @AsafKaragila So when a minimal element is unique yet not a minimum, what does that actually mean?

Comment: @J.G.: It means nothing. It means that the partial order is necessarily infinite, and that it is not well-founded (the set of those incomparable with the minimal element is non-empty and has no minimal element). Moreover, in the case where you require *every* non-empty set to admit a unique minimal element, the same argument presented in this question already implies that the order is linear, and therefore the minimal element is in fact a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

How could none of them be the last element? There is no other element in $\{x,y\}$ besides $x$ and $y$.

Comment: +1 To expand on this answer, recall that $\{x,y\}$ is nonempty since $x$ and $y$ are elements (it is still possible $x$ and $y$ are equal). Because $R$ is well-ordered, there must exist a $R$-least-element in $\{x,y\}$.