# Why there may be no single "maximum" element in a partially ordered set?

Tags: algorithms, elementary-set-theory, relations

From Appendix B.2 (relations) of [Introduction to Algorithms](http://mitpress.mit.edu/algorithms/) by Cormen et al:

> In a partially ordered set $A$, there may be no single "maximum" element $a$ such that $b R a$ for all $b ∈ A$. Instead, there may several maximal elements a such that for no $b ∈ A$, where $b ≠ a$, is it the case that $a R b$. For example, in a collection of different-sized boxes there may be several maximal boxes that don't fit inside any other box, yet no single "maximum" box into which any other box will fit.

I know the definition of a partial ordered set , but do not get why the author/authors say that "there may be no single **"maximum"** element" in a  partially ordered set ?

Comment: Some counterexamples can be found at [ProofWiki](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Maximal_Element_Not_Necessarily_Greatest_Element) and
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_element#Existence_and_uniqueness).

Comment: @MartinSleziak to understand the counter example I have to understand this one first.

Comment: Related question: [difference between maximal element and greatest element](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44774/difference-between-maximal-element-and-greatest-element).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remember that we're dealing with a **partial order**! This is fundamentally different from a *total order* like $\leq$ is on numbers.

**Because:** For all numbers, we have either $a\leq b$ or $b\leq a$, i.e. *everything is comparable*.

However a partial order is *partial* because elements **need not be comparable**. Solely if elements should happen to be comparable, then the partial order imposes some laws like transitivity.

Now take as an example the proper subsets of $\{1,2,3\}$ with the partial order of $\subseteq$. E.g. $\{1\} \subseteq \{1,2\}$, but the sets $\{1,2\}$ and $\{2,3\}$ simply are not comparable because neither includes the other. However there are no "bigger" proper subsets to each of them, so **both are maximal**.

Now if in turn all elements *were comparable*, the maximum was unique (hence in total orders it is). But in partial orders, this isn't usually the case.

Answer (score 4):

For another easy to see example, consider the set $\{1,2,3,4,6\}$ and define $a \leq b$ if $a|b$. This is a partial order, and both $4$ and $6$ are maximal elements.

Answer (score 3):

Take a finite set. Consider the lattice of subsets; this is a partially ordered set. Now, if you consider only *proper* subsets, you still have a partially ordered set, but now, every subset which consists of all elements except one is a maximal element. If you draw it, you will see it right away.

Comment: @M Turgeon What is "lattice of subsets?" Can you put a drawing in your answer somehow ?

Comment: @Geek he is talking about the power set, minus the set we're taking the power set of (boy, that's a mouthful). The partial order is given by inclusion. For example, if $S = \{a,b,c\}$ then the set he is talking about is $\{\varnothing,\{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{a,b\},\{a,c\},\{b,c\}\}$. All 3 2-element subsets of $S$ are maximal elements on $2^S-S,\subseteq$.

Comment: @Geek ProofWiki: [Subset Relation on Power Set is Partial Ordering](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Subset_Relation_on_Power_Set_is_Partial_Ordering).
You can see some Hasse diagrams as examples in Wikipedia articles on [posets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) and [Hasse diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) or [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/HasseDiagramOfPowerSets/).
(And in many other places.)

Comment: @Geek Unfortunately, I have no idea how to put pictures in my answer, but the Hasse diagrams Martin put in his comment is exactly what I meant.

Comment: @Geek I've put some diagrams also here:
[2-element set](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ai2ph.png),
[3-element set](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pc7Hr.png),
[4-element set](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mju9L.png)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that our [partial order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) is given (informally) by "box $a$ can be put into the box $b$".

If I have boxes $a$ and $b$ of the same size, I cannot put one of them into the other; this means that neither $a\le b$ nor $b\le a$ holds.

Formally, we have a partial ordering $\le=\{(a,a),(b,b)\}$ on the set $\{a,b\}$.

[Hasse diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) of this poset looks like this:

[image: Hasse]

Then $a$ and $b$ are both maximal elements. I.e., maximal element is not unique.

Comment: "if I have boxes a and b of the same size; this means that neither a≤b nor b≤a holds." .If they are of the same size(a==b) both the inequalities hold.Why are you saying neither holds ?

Comment: My relation $\le$ is defined by "a box can be put into other box"; not by comparing size. If the boxes are thick enough, I cannot put one of them into the box of the same size.

Comment: Then your relation is not reflexive, and therefore, not a partial order.

Comment: @David The relation $\{(a,a),(b,b)\}$ is reflexive. But the informal description of the example with boxes would correspond better to a [strict partial order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Strict_and_non-strict_partial_orders). (I used the boxes because I wanted to follow the example posted by OP - the one which he is asking about.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I understand your motivation. My comment is intended to highlight the ambiguity of the example *in the original post*. Your formal definition of (a) partial order is indeed one. The example given is not a good one. My response is to give a *better* one.

Comment: @DavidWheeler The relation is reflexive if the boxes can exactly fit into themselves .