# If a partial order has just one unique maximal element, must that element be a greatest element of x?

Tags: order-theory

I believe that it does not have to be a greatest element, because to be a greatest element it must be comparable to all the x in X.  I just don't know how to go about proving this.

Comment: Look here (esp the answer due to Asaf) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44774/difference-between-maximal-element-and-greatest-element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. For a ready example of a partial order with a unique maximal *and* minimal element that is neither the least nor the greatest element, take any $x\notin\Bbb Z,$ and let the relation $\precsim\::=\:\leq\cup\:\{\langle x,x\rangle\},$ where $\le$ is the order relation on $\Bbb Z.$ Then $X=\Bbb Z\cup\{x\}$ is partially ordered by $\precsim,$ and $x$ is both the unique maximal and unique minimal element, but there is no greatest or least element of $X$ under $\precsim.$

We can easily adapt this example to a partial order with a unique maximal element and a unique minimal element that are distinct from one another, but which still has no greatest or least element. We can also adapt it to an example with no minimal (maximal) element, which has a unique maximal (minimal) element but no greatest (least) element.

Comment: Excellent! It's probably easiest to see it if you make a visual. Draw a vertical sequence of dots continuing both up and down to signify the integers, with an arrow from each dot to the one immediately above it. Then to the right of that line of dots, draw another dot with no arrows to or from it, signifying $x$. This is (more or less) a [Hasse diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) for the partial order $\precsim$ that I described on the set $X$.

Comment: What does this {<x,x>} mean?

Comment: Thank you for your help with this.  Been out of school for 16 years and trying to get back what I haven't done in years.

Comment: I use $\langle x,y\rangle$ to indicate an ordered pair, so $\{\langle x,x\rangle\}$ is the set whose only member is the ordered pair with $x$ as its first and second component. (I'm glad to help.) Does that clear things up? Let me know if there's anything else you're unsure about.