# Prove/disprove questions on equivalence relations and ordered sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, relations, order-theory, equivalence-relations

> 1. If $R$ is an equivalence relation and a partial order over $A \neq \emptyset$ then every equivalence class contain at least one element.
> 2. If $(A,\le)$ an ordered set, and $a\in A$ is a single maximal element, then $a$ is the maximum.
> 3. If $(A,\le)$ an ordered set, and $a\in A$, $a$ is the maximum, then $a$ is a single maximal element.

1. It has to be true since every equivalence relation is reflexive (proof by contraposition).
2. I don't know if they meant total or partial order, so I'll suppose total order here, so we know that $a\le b$ or $b \le a$, suppose $a$ is the single maximum, there's no $b$ such that $a\le b$.
3. Here I'll suppose we have a partial order, so we have the set $\{1,2,3,4,6\}$ with the order $aRb: a|b$ so here we have a maximum 4 and 6, so there's no single maximum.

Comment: By definition *any* eq. class of *any* eq. realtion in *any* non-empty set has always at least one element...What does "is a *single* maximal element" mean? If you meant merely "a maximal element" then two is false, 3 is always true.

Comment: Usually, when one says ``ordered set" it means a partial order, not necessarily a total order. Thus I think that 2. would be false.

Comment: @DonAntonio an element that is the maximum.

Comment: @DonAntonio what should be the counter example for 2 then ? I can't use the one I used for 3. here.

Comment: @kuhaku, for a counter example for 2. take the usual $\leq$ order on $\mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$ and add $\{(a,0)\mid a\leq 0\}$ for example. You get a partial order on $A=\mathbb{Z}$ with $0$ a single maximal element, but no maximum.

Comment: @DKal you mean union of the two sets right ?

Comment: @kuhaku, yes, I mean $$\{(a,b)\mid a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}, a\leq b\}\cup\{(a,0)\mid a\in\mathbb{Z}, a\leq 0\}.$$

Comment: @kuhaku, BTW, you can just as well take $$\{(a,b)\mid a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}, a\leq b\}\cup \{(0,0)\}.$$

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44774/difference-between-maximal-element-and-greatest-element