# Lower bounded lattice to complete lattice

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

My problem is to show that any lower-bounded lattice satisfying the maximal condition is a complete lattice.

Let's call the lattice $L$. I'm having some trouble with this. I have tried to look at it from a maximal condition perspective. I saw two directions I could potentially go. One was to use the fact that the maximal condition is equivalent to the ACC in partial orders and see if I could do something with that, but I got nothing. The other direction I tried was to gather the maximal elements from each subset. I noticed that this was necessarily an anti-chain (maximal, no less). But I couldn't really see how this could help either.

I'm sure this is easier than I think. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximal condition says that every non-empty subset has a maximal element; ie there's an totally-defined set-valued operation $max$ such that for any subset $S$ we have that $\max S \neq \emptyset$ (!) and $$\forall m \in \max S; s \in S :: m \not< s \text{ and } m \in S$$

To show completeness, it suffices to show that every subset has an infimum (or equivalently supremum).

Recall for a set $S$ and an element $i$, that:

$
\;\;\;\; i \text{ greatest lower bound of } S
\\\equiv i \text{ lower bound of } S \text{ and greatest such bound}
\\\equiv i \in lbd \, S \text{ and } \forall l \in lbd \, S :: l \leq i, \text{ where lower bounds: } lbd \, T := \{l \,|\, (\forall t \in T :: l \leq t)\}
\\\equiv i \in lbd \, S  \text{ and } \forall l \in lbd \, S :: i \not< l \text{ and } \forall l \in lbd \, S :: l \leq i
\\\equiv i \in \max(lbd \, S)  \text{ and } i \in ubd(lbd \, S), \text{ where uppers: } ubd \, T := \{u \,|\, (\forall t \in T :: t \leq u)\} 
\\\equiv i \in \max(lbd \, S) \,\cap\, ubd(lbd \, S)
$

Now with the given, it remains to show that this set $E := \max(lbd \, S) \,\cap\, ubd(lbd \, S)$ is non-empty, if $S$ is nonempty, and is in fact a singleton set $\{ e \}$. Then we define, $\inf S := e$.

I've personally not made these checks; if you make them, please post them.

---

From the comments: Let L be a lower-bounded lattice satisfying the maximal condition and let X be an arbitrary subset of L. Since L is lower bounded, lbd(X) is non-empty, and hence has at least one maximal element. To see that max(lbd(X)) is a singleton, let a,b∈max(lbd(X)). Then, since L is a lattice, a∨b exists, call it c. We claim that c∈lbd(X). <-- Here is where I need help. If I can show that, then a=b=c and there would be no elements in lbd(X) that are greater than c, hence c must be ⋀X.

You've shown *$max \ lbd \ X$ has at-least one element*;
($\bot \in L \implies \bot \in lbd \ X \implies max \ lbd \ X \neq \emptyset$).

It remains to show that *$max \ lbd \ X$ has at-most one element*.
Let $a,b$ be in that set, then

$\;\;\;a,b \in max \ lbd \ X
\\\Rightarrow a,b \in lbd \ X \;\;\text{ by defn of max}
\\\equiv \forall x \in X :: a,b \leq x \;\;\text{ defn of lbd}
\\\Rightarrow \forall x \in X :: a \vee b \leq x \text{ since $x$ is upper bound of $a,b$ means it's at-least the least upper bound of $a,b$}
\\\equiv a \vee b \in lbd \ X \;\;\text{ by defn of lbd }
$

Now we have $a,b \in max \ lbd \ X$ and $a \vee b \in lbd \ X$.
But by maximality we then have $a,b \not< a \vee b$, ie
$a = a \vee b = b$. Hence, *$max \ lbd \ X$ has exactly one element* :)

Let us call this unique element $m$, then according to the calculation way above in this post, we need to show that $m \in ubd \ lbd \ X$ in order to conclude that $m$ is in-fact the glb of $X$.

(See [difference between maximal element and greatest element](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44774/difference-between-maximal-element-and-greatest-element) )

Comment: First off, thanks for your answer! I hadn't considered the intersection you ended up with. So, let $L$ be the lattice given in the question. My definition of completeness says that every subset must have an infimum (or equivalently, a supremum) in $L$. How do we show that $i\in L$?

Comment: I guess my definitions could've been more precise. I should've indicated that $lbd T, ubd T \subseteq L$ if $T \subseteq L$, and consequently the aforementioned $E \subseteq L$. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Yes, that helps a lot. It's just hard to see sometimes. Thanks for your help! EDIT: I wonder if I can use this argument: Suppose to the contrary that there exists a subset, $S$, of $L$ that has no infimum. Then it's lower bound set $lbd(S)$ has no elements or an infinite number of elements as it cannot have a greatest element. $lbd(S)$ is non-empty since $L$ itself is bounded, so $lbd(S)$ must be infinite. This cannot happen since $L$ satisfies the maximal condition and thus the ascending chain condition. Hence $lbd(S)$ must have a maximum, namely, the $inf(S)$.

Comment: Things seem fine, but I think the following sentence needs a bit more elaboration...

`This cannot happen since L satisfies the maximal condition and thus the ascending chain condition. Hence lbd(S) must have a maximum, namely, the inf(S)`

Comment: I ended up trying a different way. Here's what I have so far: Let $L$ be a lower-bounded lattice satisfying the maximal condition and let $X$ be an arbitrary subset of $L$. Since $L$ is lower bounded, $lbd(X)$ is non-empty, and hence has at least one maximal element. To see that $max(lbd(X))$ is a singleton, let $a,b\in max(lbd(X))$. Then, since $L$ is a lattice, $a\vee b$ exists, call it $c$. We claim that $c\in lbd(X)$. <-- Here is where I need help. If I can show that, then $a = b = c$ and there would be no elements in $lbd(X)$ that are greater than $c$, hence $c$ must be $\bigwedge X$.

Comment: This seems good, but I feel the comments section is a bit stuffy for calculation, so I'm going up into the "answer" area.

Comment: `hence c must be ⋀X` ... be careful: $x \not< y \equiv y \leq x$ does not hold in general! It holds in the case where $\leq$ is linear/total.

Comment: I see now. Thanks for sticking with me! I feel like there's not much left to show. Suppose that $m$ is not the infimum. Then there exists an $x\in lbd(X)$ so that $m\leq x$. But then, by the maximality of $m$, $m = x$. Hence there can be no element greater than $m$ and so $m$ must be the greatest lower bound.

Comment: I'm a bit slow :( Please make the justifications explicit.

Eg, "Suppose that m is not the infimum. Then there exists an x∈lbd(X) so that m≤x" :: did you mean, "so that NOT(x≤m)"? Otherwise please justify explicitly.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I meant to add that $m\neq x$. The contradiction is then immediate. Thanks again for your help!